# Mimic iii - Are the months of the year accurate to the actual months?

Tags: mimic-iii

According to the Mimic III documentation:

> All dates in the database have been shifted to protect patient
>   confidentiality. Dates will be internally consistent for the same
>   patient, but randomly distributed in the future. Dates of birth which
>   occur in the present time are not true dates of birth. Furthermore,
>   dates of birth which occur before the year 1900 occur if the patient
>   is older than 89. In these cases, the patient’s age at their first
>   admission has been fixed to 300.

My question is whether the month/day/time information has been obfuscated as well... ie if the subject's `ADMITTIME` is stored as `4/11/2172 19:40` - can I reliably say that the actual patient was admitted on April 11th in "some year" or has all of that information been shifted as well?

Comment: Since the documentation says the dates are "randomly distributed" in the future, it would seem that the months are probably NOT accurate, thus limiting a seasonal analysis.

Comment: See here: seasonality is somewhat preserved: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/mimic-iii-days-of-the-week?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **No** - you can't extract accurate month, day or year data from MIMIC.

De-identification diagram:
[image]

The de-identification example actually shows that the month, day and year are all shifted.

As @Gary Weissman pointed out in the question comments, the days of the week and "approximate" seasonality are preserved in MIMIC II, and MIMIC III [follows the same de-identification process.](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/mimic-iii-days-of-the-week?rq=1)

> > 1.4.4 De-identification of patients’ data [...]
>
> • The day of the week and season of the year were preserved.

The complete information can be found [here](http://mimic.physionet.org/archive/mimic-ii-guide.pdf)